# How to identify different id's that start with the same but vary in a value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Hello I'm trying to do something with JavaScript/CoffeeScript and Ruby on Rails:
I've got several comments (rendered over a for each iteration) of which I want to show something under each of them when I click a button in that comment.
I've done this for id'ing the buttons and the sections inside the code that renders each comment:

```
<div>
    <a id="show-link-<%=comment.id%>" href="#">
        This will show whats in the section
    </a>
</div>
<section id="show-section-<%=comment.id%>">
    This is what I want to show
</section>
```

And then I want to do this in coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#show-link-[SOMEID]').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#show-section-[SOMEID]').toggle()
```

And I want the script to detect which button was clicked and show its respective section, for each comment.
The SOMEID in the script would be the possibility to identify some number there and use it inside the function.
Hope you can help, and thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not just have the click event handler show the `nextElementSibling` of `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all you have is a hammer...

You're using a wrong tool for the job (trying to embed data in an id).

This is much better done using data attributes and classes. Use a class to mass-assign click handler and use a data attribute to store section name in full form, which does not require any processing.

```
<div>
    <a class='show-link' data-section-id="show-section-<%= comment.id %>" href="#">
        This will show whats in the section
    </a>
</div>
<section id="show-section-<%= comment.id %>">
    This is what I want to show
</section>
```

Then

```
$('.show-link').click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  commentSectionId = $(this).data('sectionId')
  $('#' + commentSectionId).toggle()
```

#### Demo

```js
$('.show-link').click(function(event) {
  var commentSectionId;
  event.preventDefault();
  commentSectionId = $(this).data('sectionId');
  return $("#" + commentSectionId).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
        <a class='show-link' data-section-id="show-section-1" href="#">
            This will show whats in the section
        </a>
    </div>
    <section id="show-section-1" style='display: none'>
        This is what I want to show
    </section>
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, except for the last line of the script, as when adding alert(commentSectionId) before that line, that variable is the right one for each comment, but the toggle() part doesn't seem to be working.
And yes I'm pretty inexpert at this topic, but thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MacuDuranti: note the double `##`

Comment: I was using `'` instead of `"`, changed it but everything is the same. And yes I'm using the double ##

Comment: @MacuDuranti: did you also reload the page? I am quite confident that it should work.

Comment: Yes I did several times, I don't get why it isn't working, I've never used the double `##` but guess it should work. Here a screenshot of what I get when clicking the button, and the code of the page (ids are matching):
http://imgur.com/a/b9kuQ
(Sorry for the website being in spanish and the changed names)
This is the coffescript:
`$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.respuestas-link').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    commentSectionId = $(this).data('sectionId')
    alert(commentSectionId)
  $("##{commentSectionId}").toggle()`
Thanks a lot for your time @sergio

Comment: @MacuDuranti: Try `$('#' + commentSectionId).toggle()`.

Comment: Tried that too, getting this error in the console when inspecting on Chrome:
answers.self-6aca2e0….js?body=1:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: commentSectionId is not defined(…)
But the alert sentence is showing it right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129839/discussion-between-macu-duranti-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the ruby or coffeescript, but how about just using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and `this`?

```js
// Get all the "buttons"
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".showLink");

// Loop the "buttons" and wire an event handler to the click event
links.forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    // Find the parent of the "button" (the <div>)
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    
    // Go to that div element's next sibling and show it:
    parent.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("class", "show");
  });
});
```

```css
.section {display:none;}
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div>
    <a id="show-link-<%=comment.id%>" href="#" class="showLink">
        This will show whats in the section
    </a>
</div>
<section id="show-section-<%=comment.id%>" class="section">
    Section 1 Content
</section>

<div>
    <a id="show-link-<%=comment.id%>" href="#" class="showLink">
        This will show whats in the section
    </a>
</div>
<section id="show-section-<%=comment.id%>" class="section">
    Section 2 Content
</section>

<div>
    <a id="show-link-<%=comment.id%>" href="#" class="showLink">
        This will show whats in the section
    </a>
</div>
<section id="show-section-<%=comment.id%>" class="section">
    Section 3 Content
</section>
```